# Sorting Issue in Hierarchical Query

Tags: sql, sorting, hierarchical

I have following data in hierarchical shape wherein I would like to add parentid wise sub totals.

But I am unable to sort the data as per my requirement, kindly help me out.

- Raw data:

  [image]
- Required data:

  [image]

The key is that after level 4, its descendent nodes should be printed, which I managed to add with Union All Query, but I can't figure out how to sort, so that node no. 1.1.1 of group 2 should be printed after node 1.1.1.4, then 1.1 then 1, and so on.

I am using sql server database.

Kindly help me out on this.

Thanks / Luqman

```
create table mytable 
    (id int primary key, 
    node varchar(50) not null, 
    type char(1) not null, 
    lvl int, 
    amt decimal(10,2), 
    parentid int);

insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(1,'1','H',1,NULL,0); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(2,'1.1','H',2,1,0); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(3,'1.1.1','H',3,2,0); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(4,'1.1.1.1','D',4,3,1000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(5,'1.1.1.2','D',4,3,2000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(6,'1.1.1.3','D',4,3,3000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(7,'1.1.1.4','D',4,3,4000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(8,'2','H',1,NULL,0); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(9,'2.1','H',2,8,0); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(10,'2.1.1','H',3,9,0); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(11,'2.1.1.1','D',4,10,1000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(12,'2.1.1.2','D',4,10,2000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(13,'2.1.1.3','D',4,10,3000); 
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(14,'2.1.1.4','D',4,10,4000);


select * from mytable 
union all select * from mytable 
where type='H'
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us your current query. also provide text for the data instead of a picture please.

Comment: What an odd requirement. I expect this may involve writing records to a 'temp' table. An order identifier would have to be created and saved with each record.

Comment: Oops? Raw data for 1.1.1 shows Group 1 in both cases.  Also, posting the data a JPG prevents me from copying it, and thus greatly decreases the motivation to duplicate your data in my db or attempt to create sql that solves the problem.

Comment: Regret, my first time, so may be could not explained well. I need to create a report where the hierarchical sum to be displayed at the bottom instead of at the top. I am trying to paste my queries here but characters limit of this box not allowing me. Also this comment box not allowing me to press Enter Key. Please help me how do I post my queries.

Comment: create table mytable
(id int primary key,
node varchar(50) not null,
type char(1) not null,
lvl int,
amt decimal(10,2),
parentid int);

Comment: insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(1,'1','H',1,NULL,0);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(2,'1.1','H',2,1,0);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(3,'1.1.1','H',3,2,0);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(4,'1.1.1.1','D',4,3,1000);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(5,'1.1.1.2','D',4,3,2000);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(6,'1.1.1.3','D',4,3,3000);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(7,'1.1.1.4','D',4,3,4000);

Comment: insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(8,'2','H',1,NULL,0);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(9,'2.1','H',2,8,0);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(10,'2.1.1','H',3,9,0);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(11,'2.1.1.1','D',4,10,1000);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(12,'2.1.1.2','D',4,10,2000);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(13,'2.1.1.3','D',4,10,3000);
insert into mytable (id,node,type,lvl,parentid,amt) values(14,'2.1.1.4','D',4,10,4000);

Comment: select * from mytable
union all
select * from mytable where type='H'

Comment: Level Node Title Amount
1 1   World 
2 1.1     Continents 
3 1.1.1       Asia  2,000.00 
3 1.1.2       Europe  5,000.00 
3 1.1.3       North America  5,000.00 
2 1.1     Total Continents  12,000.00 
1 1   Total World  12,000.00 
   
I need report something like above.